# How to clip sibling divs

Tags: css, user-interface, sass

I achieved this [image: this] effect in figma by clipping an ellipse shape to the cards.

Now I tried in css [image: css] with no luck. How do I remove the ellipse shape overflow of its sibling divs

HTML

```
<div className='parent-div'>
        <div className=''>div1</div>
        <div className=''>div2</div>
        <div className=''>div3</div>
        <div className='shape'></div>
      </div>
```

SASS

```
.parent-div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  div {
    background: rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.8);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: solid 1.5px #303030;
  }
  .shape {
    background: #ea0599;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 900px;
    top: 250px;
    filter: blur(100px);
    opacity: 0.5;
    mix-blend-mode: plus-lighter;
  }
}
```